# How to load a xml file in plugins webroot

Tags: cakephp, plugins, components, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp-3.0

In a Component of a plugin, I want to load a XML file in the plugins webroot.

```
simplexml_load_file('RangeMessage.xml')
```

The file can't be found. Debugging the path with

```
debug(realpath(''));
```

Says, that the actual directory is `/path/to/app/webroot`.
My xml-file however is in `/path/to/app/plugins/myPlugin/webroot`
So how can I find the file without using the absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Plugin::path()` to retrieve the absolute path to your plugin, so you don't have to hardcode it.

```
Plugin::path('YourPlugin') . 'webroot' . DS . 'RangeMessage.xml'
```

See also **[API > Cake\Core\Plugin::path()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#_path)**

Comment: This works perfekt. Is this by the way a bug or a feature? If e.g. a javascript is importet in a plugins view, it works exactly the same way like in the app.

Comment: @MatthiasMoritz I don't really get what you are referring to. The working directory pointing to the apps `webroot` folder is just how PHP works, it's the path where the initially invoked script file (`index.php`) lives.